# Halting behavior of a randomly selected Turing machine?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Let $TM(k,2)$ be the set of Turing machines with $k$-states and $2$ symbols.  Let $h(k)$ be the number of machines in $TM(k,2)$ that halt when run on the blank input.

Is
$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{h(k)}{|TM(k,2)|} = 0$? That is, do most Turing machines not halt?

I guess related to this, I would be interested in hearing about any non-trivial bounds on $h(k)$.  I guess as a variation, I would be interested in bounds for the smaller function $h_{all}(k)$ that counts the Turing machines on $k$-states that halt on all possible inputs.

I am sure precise bounds depend on the specific model of Turing machines, however maybe the above limit question does not.

Thanks for the thoughts!

Comment: It is also related to the chosen enumeration. A similar question (and good answer) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73187/density-of-halting-turing-machines).

Comment: Thanks @MarzioDeBiasi - following your link, we get to another [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70397/turing-machines-that-read-the-entire-program-tape/70453#70453) that says that the above limit is in fact 1.